# How to display only the value in edit page in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

I have a edit form in Active Admin. I need some field as read only.

My current edit page is like

[image]

I need the page look like this

[image]

How can this be done. My code for the edit form page is like

```
    form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|  
      f.inputs "Users" do
        f.input :device, :label => 'Device', :as => :select, :collection => DEVICE, :include_blank => false
        f.input :current_address, :label => 'Current Address', :as => :string
      end
    end
```

Please help.

Comment: actually what i did is I added disabled => true, I see the disabled text box. I styled the background of the text box to match the page color. So it looks like what I need. but that's not the correct way :(

Comment: It's a pity, it could be good option

Answer (score 53):

As Alex said, set to disabled.  You could then use css to get the visual you wanted, if you can live with the semantics of that.

The syntax was slightly different for me to get this to work.

in your admin form:

```
 f.input :finish_position, input_html: { disabled: true }
```

in your CSS active_admin.css

```
input[disabled="disabled"],
input[disabled] {
  background-color: #F4F4F4;
  border: 0px solid #F4F4F4 !important;  
}
```

Comment: THX a lot @Will I did a small change to the css to emphasize the idea of a disabled "field": I've substituted `border: 0px solid #F4F4F4 !important;` with `cursor: not-allowed;`

Answer (score 14):

For a cleaner form definition within your ActiveAdmin.register{} block you may as well want to define a "readonly" input type to be used within active admin using formtastic:

Form block syntax is for activeadmin version 1.0.0.pre at 0becbef0918a.

```
# app/admin/inputs/readonly_input.rb

class ReadonlyInput < Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
  def to_html
    input_wrapping do
      label_html <<
      template.content_tag('div', @object.send(method))
    end
  end
end

# app/admin/your_model.rb

ActiveAdmin.register YourModel do
  # ...

  form do |f|
    # ...

    input :current_address, as: :readonly

    # ...
  end  
end
```

Comment: will this send the value to the controller when the form is submitted?

Comment: No it won't — not sure why it needs to, since theoretically it's showing the already-saved value of the field.

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same issue and tried using `:disabled` but it did not solve my problem as I wanted `field` value to be included in `params` object while sending it to the server. When you mark a `form input` as `:input_html => {:disabled => true}` , it does not include this field value in `params`.
So, instead I used `:input_html => {:readonly => true}` which solved both of my problems:

1. Does not allow user to `edit`
2. Includes the value in `params`

I hope this will help.

Comment: `:input_html => {:disabled => true}` , it does not include this field value in params

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|  
  f.inputs "Users" do
    f.input :device, :label => 'Device', :as => :select, :collection => DEVICE, :include_blank => false
    f.li do
      f.label :current_address
      f.span f.object.current_address
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `, :disabled => true` for address input field.

Comment: when I add :disabled => ture I can see the textbox there, and it wont be editable. Actually I dont wan't any textbox there.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to use "object". Here is how you should code it:

```
form :html => { :enctype => "multipart/form-data" } do |f|  
  f.inputs "Users" do
    f.input :device, :label => 'Device', :as => :select, :collection => DEVICE, :include_blank => false
    f.label :current_address, f.object.current_address
  end
end
```